# Stretch to Improve Arm Closing Flexibility

Tags: stretching, flexibility, arms

I'm noticing as I build muscle that it's harder for me to close my arm all the way -- the motion you would use to touch your fist to your shoulder.

I've noticed little things so far:

- it's harder to reach my collar to insert collar stays
- when I do bench presses, as I get near the bottom of my lift, I can feel the stretch in my arm where I couldn't before

What are good stretches to improve my flexibility here? Am I looking for tricep stretches? General arm stretches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that would be your triceps.  Try the three stretches shown below:

---

[image]

1.) Place your hand on the opposite elbow as show below and the elbow and gently pull it across your body until you feel a stretch.

---

[image]

2.) Standing in a doorway with your palms facing forward with your arms at shoulder level lean forward.

---

[image]
3.) Pull your arm slightly towards you.